# I try to connect django with postgreSQL on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am newbie on django , and I am facing the following issue. I have search for solution on the web but I couldn't find any yet.

```
 File "/home/r00t/projects/mp/mp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 187, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/home/r00t/projects/mp/mp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: invalid port number: "<5432>"
```

settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql'
        'NAME': '<mpdb>',
        'USER': '<admin>',
        'PASSWORD': '<r00t>',
        'HOST': '<127.0.0.1>',       
        'PORT': '<5432>',
    }
}
```

I have tried the following:
port no: correct
database name: correct
user name: correct
password: correct

Could you please help me out with
thanks

Comment: why do you have < > characters

Answer (score 0):

When you see `<foo>` in descriptions or examples, it usually means you are supposed to replace those contents *including the angle brackets* with the real value.  So after replacement the angle brackets are no longer there.  It looks like you have left the literal `<` and `>` in place, which is wrong.